# My console did not show any array value when getting an id from input value of ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i try to check in console whether the array value is exist or not....but nothing shows from my console log...the value was from the multiple checkbox input....

here is my code with checkbox inside ajax

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ route('reporting.getBranchAjax',['cuid','stid']) }}",
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    cuid: cuid,
    stid: stid
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.branch.length);

    for (var x = 0; x < data.branch.length; x++) {
      //console.log(data.branch[x].cb_branch_Name);
      $('#brRecord').append(`<tr><td style='width: 110px; text-align: left;'>${data.branch[x].cb_branchcode}
    </td><td style='width: 600px; text-align: 
    left;'>${data.branch[x].cb_branch_Name}</td> 
    <td style='width: 20px;'> <input type="checkbox" class="ss" name="ss_" id="ss_" value="${data.branch[x].ID}^${data.branch[x].cb_branchcode}^${data.branch[x].cb_branch_Name}" /></td><td> </td></tr>`);

    }


  },
  fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('request failed');
  }
})
}
var total = document.getElementById('brRecord').rows.length;
var logNo = "";
var arrayTotal = new Array();
for (var i = 1, j = 0; i <= total; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("ss_").checked == true) {
    arrayTotal[j] = document.getElementById("ss_").value;
    j++;
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < arrayTotal.length; i++) {
  logNo = logNo + arrayTotal[i]
  if ((arrayTotal.length - i != 1)) {
    logNo = logNo + ",";
  }
}


console.log(logNo);
```

```html
<tbody id="brRecord">
</tbody>
```

i expect all my array value from input multiple checkbox show in console

Comment: Check if the below consoles get printed, if not , try checking in your browser console if log levels for log is enabled also. ```console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.branch.length);```

Comment: use POST instead of GET

Comment: `console.log(logNo);` will always return empty or null, since you're running an async ajax call, so the checkboxes haven't been appended yet when it reaches that point in your code.